# why can't I open/ interact with files through python

Tags: python, file, operating-system

I'm new to coding and have started to try out the OS module, it occasionally it will work on specific paths.
example:

but when I try to interact with an individual file this will happen:

```
print(os.stat('my_file.txt'))

>>>filenotfounderror: [errno 2] no such file or directory found. 
'my_file.txt'
```

or when I try to interact with a path that is not in my cwd then this would happen:

```
print(os.listdir(C:\folder\folder\folder))

>>>SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in 
position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

I don't understand why this is happening and it would be great if someone could explain why this is happening, thanks.

Comment: You don't have quotes around `C:\folder\folder\folder`

Comment: whoops, i just missed that when writing the question but this was not in the script. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python tells your that `my_file.txt` does not exist in the current directory in your first example.

Verify that you have a file called `my_file.txt` and then check the current working directory of your python process with [os.getcwd()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd).

For your second example, in python the backslash `\` is a special character for [escape sequences in a string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals). For example the linefeed `\n` or the tab `\t`.

The error in your example is most likely the result of accidentaly forming an invalid escape sequence by not escaping the backslash itself like this:

```
print(os.listdir('C:\\folder\\folder\\folder'))
```

Comment: my_file.txt is just an example file just as \folder\folder\folder is. but yes i do have the correct file name in my script. ahhhhh so i have to change my cwd using os.chdir and then i can access the file within that directory. the double back slash also worked. thanks allot for the help

Comment: @BOBTHEBUILDER Or you can use the full path of `my_file.txt` instead of changing directory.